# How do I install Composer without cURL command line?

Tags: php, curl, composer-php

I need to install Composer on a shared hosting service. This service supports cURL, but does not support SSH access. As a result, I cannot run cURL commands from the command line.

Is it possible to install cURL without a command line? Perhaps a PHP script that I run only once?

Comment: In this case, I would say it is best to simply use Composer to install all of your dependencies locally and upload everything to your server over SFTP or FTP.

Comment: probably on shared hosting you won't be able execute command line commands from PHP (shell_exec will be blocked). 
You can download everything on your computer and then copy the files over the network

Comment: Okay. So, I can install Composer on my WAMP server locally, and then copy all the files on my WAMP server over to the remote server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [download page](https://getcomposer.org/download/) of the composer site has instructions for those missing curl that only require php:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

The above is the recommended way, but alternatively if you don't want to run the installer and all the config checks it does, you can just download the phar file from https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar - either using your browser or via `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar` (if you have access to wget).

Comment: What happened to the curl instructions for downloading Composer? `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

Answer (score 5):

Install the `composer.phar` file locally and then just upload it to your hosting provider.

Alternatively, you can download [`composer.phar`](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar) from their website.

However, it's unlikely that you'll be able to run it. Unless you are using it programatically, I recommend you install all of your dependencies locally into a release branch/package and upload that to your hosting provider.

Comment: I'm super new to PHP and everything, so I'm not sure I understand your post.

If I understood correctly, what you are saying is that instead of simply transferring the composer.phar to the remote server, I should actually install the composer.phar on my local WAMP server using the command line. _And then_ I have to transfer it to the remote server.

Am I right?

Comment: Almost. Composer is a tool/helper to install other extensions, modules, etc. He said you can install composer locally, install what you need about composer locally, and at the end upload all the bundle to the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file from https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar

And then use with php prefix of every commands.

Example of a batch on windows OS:
`C:\xampp\php\php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel42 4.2 --prefer-dist`

You can also create a simple batch file to do it globally:

```
:: File Name should composer.bat
@ECHO OFF
SET PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0
setlocal DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=5000
C:\xampp\php\php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*
```

Now you are able to use it VIA evnironment setup or directly to this batch file.