# How to install laravel 5 in cpanel?

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

So here is the issue with my Host. I am trying to install composer on the remote ssh and this is the response i get from the host. They told me they are not blocking anything from their side.

```
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  Could not open input file: 
    curl: (23) Failed writing body (251 != 16384)
```

Can anyone suggest how to install this on remote site ?

Comment: Just get a new host. Use Laravel Forge and setup a server on DigitalOcean in like 5mins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing composer with `php` or `wget` first.

1) `php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`

2) `wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar`

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22458659/1348344

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo`?
What response do you get?

Comment: same error. My host emailed me back saying "We do not support this technology."

Comment: I'd try asking him to install composer. If not willing, I'd change a host. This is must have for PHP development and not-using it would be really slowing down your work.